# Are there alternative methods for saying 'next' in a pl/sql for loop?

Tags: oracle, plsql, controls, for-loop

So I've got a for loop that processes a list of IDs and has some fairly complex things to do. Without going into all the ugly details, basically this:

```
    DECLARE
      l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

      ...snip...
    BEGIN

      -- get the list ids
      l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P4_SELECT_LIST);
      -- process each in a nice loop
      FOR i IN 1..l_selected.count 
      LOOP
        -- do some data checking stuff...

        -- here we will look for duplicate entries, so we can noop if duplicate is found
        BEGIN
          SELECT county_id INTO v_dup_check FROM org_county_accountable
          WHERE organization_id = :P4_ID AND county_id = v_county_id;
          -- NEXT;! NOOP;! but there is no next!
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('no dups found, proceeding');
        END;
        -- here we have code we only want to execute if there are no dupes already
        IF v_dup_check IS NULL THEN
          -- if not a duplicate record, proceed...

        ELSE
          -- reset duplicate check variable
          v_dup_check := NULL;
        END;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

How I normally handle this is by selecting into a value, and then wrap the following code in an IF statement checking to make sure that duplicate check variable is NULL. But it's annoying. I just want to be able to say NEXT; or NOOP; or something. Especially since I already have to catch the NO_DATA_FOUND exception. I suppose I could write a letter to Oracle, but I'm curious how others handle this.

I could also wrap this in a function, too, but I was looking for something a little cleaner/simpler.

Comment: Nice to see someone else using APEX!

Comment: APEX rocks, man ;-) The forum on forums.oracle.com is really helpful.

Comment: In your question and both tuinstoel and Pourquoi's solutions, you're performing an additional SQL query (and context switch to/from PL/SQL) in every iteration of your FOR loop...that's not necessarily cheap.  If performance is a concern, it'd be better to remove all dups up front in a single query.

Comment: jimmyorr, that's a really good point, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of rows is also possible (see Pourquoi Litytestdata) but you can also do what you want to do in the `when_no_data_found exception` block.

```
declare 
  l_selected    apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  l_county_id   org_county_accountable.count_id%type;
begin
  l_selected := apex_util.string_to_table(:p4_select_lst);
  for i in l_selected.first..l_selected.last loop
    begin
      select count_id
      into   l_county_id
      from   org_county_accountable
      where  organization_id = :p4_id
      and    county_id       = v_county_id;
    exception
      when no_data_found then 
        -- here we have code we only want to execute if there are no dupes already
        -- if not a duplicate record, proceed...
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 11g adds a C-style "continue" loop construct to PL/SQL, which syntactically sounds like what you're looking for.

For your purposes, why not just eliminate the duplicates prior to entering the loop?  This could be done by querying l_selected using a table function, and then filtering out records you don't want instead of iterating over **every** value.  Something like...

```
declare

l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

cursor no_dups_cur (p_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2) is 
  select * from (
  select selected.*, 
         count(*) over (partition by county_id) cnt -- analytic to find counts grouped by county_id
    from table(p_selected) selected -- use table function to treat VC_ARR2 like a table 
    ) where cnt = 1 -- remove records that have duplicate county_ids
    ;

begin

l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P4_SELECT_LIST);

for i in no_dups_cur(l_selected) loop

  null; -- do whatever to non-duplicates 

end loop;

end;
```

Just substitute the logic for determining a "duplicate" with your own (didn't have enough info from your example to really answer that part)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of catching `NO_DATA_FOUND`, how about SELECTing the number of matching entries into a variable, say `l_count`, and proceeding if this count works out to be zero?  Something like the following:

```
    DECLARE
      l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
      l_count    INTEGER;

      ...snip...
    BEGIN

      -- get the list ids
      l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P4_SELECT_LIST);
      -- process each in a nice loop
      FOR i IN 1..l_selected.count 
      LOOP
        -- do some data checking stuff...

        -- here we will count duplicate entries, so we can noop if duplicate is found
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM org_county_accountable
         WHERE organization_id = :P4_ID AND county_id = v_county_id;
        IF l_count = 0 THEN
          -- here we have code we only want to execute if there are no dupes already
          -- if not a duplicate record, proceed...

        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```
<xmp>
<<next_loop>>
loop
...
...
if ....
then
   goto next_loop;

</xmp>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where a GOTO statement *might* be useful. See the [Oracle Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#BCGFGDAA) in the control structures to see how to do this. Also, you may want to search around here to find out how to query for the existence of a record. Running a query and waiting for an exception isn't optimal.

Comment: That's actually a really tight solution, the GOTO statement, thanks! 

I don't quite get the rest of your answer. I'm more than happy to query duplicate records, it's necessary. Although, I like the idea of selecting a count better, since there's no exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Another way - turn the check into a local function:

```
DECLARE
  l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;

  ...snip...
  FUNCTION dup_exists 
     ( p_org_id org_county_accountable.organization_id%TYPE
     , p_county_id org_county_accountable.county_id%TYPE
     ) RETURN BOOLEAN 
  IS
    v_dup_check org_county_accountable.county_id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT county_id INTO v_dup_check FROM org_county_accountable
    WHERE organization_id = p_org_id AND county_id = p_county_id;
    RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
  END;
BEGIN

  -- get the list ids
  l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P4_SELECT_LIST);
  -- process each in a nice loop
  FOR i IN 1..l_selected.count
  LOOP
    -- do some data checking stuff...

    -- here we have code we only want to execute if there are no dupes already
    IF NOT dup_exists (:P4_ID, v_county_id) THEN
      -- if not a duplicate record, proceed...

    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Of course, the local function could be re-written to use the count method if you prefer:

```
  FUNCTION dup_exists 
     ( p_org_id org_county_accountable.organization_id%TYPE
     , p_county_id org_county_accountable.county_id%TYPE
     ) RETURN BOOLEAN 
  IS
    l_count INTEGER;
  BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count 
       FROM org_county_accountable
      WHERE organization_id = p_org_id AND county_id = p_county_id;
     RETURN (l_count > 0);
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to raise and handle a user-defined exception:

```
DECLARE
  l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
  duplicate_org_county EXCEPTION;

  ...snip...
BEGIN

  -- get the list ids
  l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P4_SELECT_LIST);
  -- process each in a nice loop
  FOR i IN 1..l_selected.count 
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      -- do some data checking stuff...

      -- here we will look for duplicate entries, so we can noop if duplicate is found
      BEGIN
        SELECT county_id INTO v_dup_check FROM org_county_accountable
        WHERE organization_id = :P4_ID AND county_id = v_county_id;
        RAISE duplicate_org_county;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('no dups found, proceeding');
      END;
      -- here we have code we only want to execute if there are no dupes already

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN duplicate_org_county THEN NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I wouldn't normally do this, but if there were half a dozen reasons to jump to the next record, this might be preferable to multiple nested IFs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldie but I couldn't help notice that none of the answers above take into account the cursor [attributes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/langpkt/ch01_09.htm):

There are four attributes associated with cursors: ISOPEN, FOUND, NOTFOUND, and ROWCOUNT. These attributes can be accessed with the % delimiter to obtain information about the state of the cursor.

The syntax for a cursor attribute is:

```
cursor_name%attribute
```

where  cursor_name is the name of the explicit cursor.

So in this case you could use ROWCOUNT (which indicates the number of rows fetched so far) for your purposes, like this:

```
declare 
   aux number(10) := 0;
   CURSOR cursor_name is select * from table where something;
begin
     select count(*) into aux from table where something;
     FOR row IN cursor_name LOOP
        IF(aux > cursor_name%ROWCOUNT) THEN 'do something is not over';
        ELSE 'do something else';
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
end;
```